# date command invalid date when determining age of AWS keys

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have to report on the last time that AWS keys were used. I'm using bash for this script. If a key has not been used the value is 'null' and I have to account for that.

When I try to use the date command I get these errors:

```
date: invalid date ‘"2018-07-13T14:49:00Z"’
date: invalid date ‘null’
```

This is my code, I'm trying to use to print those values:

```
if [[ "$key1_last_used" = 'null' ]]; then
    key1_last_used="key was never used."
   else
     key1_last_used=$(date --date $key1_last_used_date "+%B %d %Y")
   fi
```

If I determine the age of the key with this command:

```
aws iam  get-access-key-last-used --access-key-id AKIAISEHPFM2DRIMIXXQ  --profile=nonprod  | jq '.AccessKeyLastUsed.LastUsedDate'
```

And get this response back:

```
"2018-07-13T14:57:00Z"
```

The code then runs this date command:

```
date --date '"2018-07-13T15:01:00Z"' '+%B %d %Y'
```

And produces this result:

```
date: invalid date ‘"2018-07-13T15:01:00Z"’
```

If I then encounter a key that has not been used:

```
aws iam get-access-key-last-used --access-key-id AKIAIDZ7X4JCS5ANNXGQ --profile=nonprod | jq '.AccessKeyLastUsed.LastUsedDate'
```

I get this response back:

```
null
```

When the date command is run, null is considered invalid input:

```
date --date null '+%B %d %Y'
date: invalid date ‘null’
```

I don't know why the date is not printing correctly. Where are those extra quotes coming from? And I don't know why the if /then is not recognizing the null output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jq -r` to get the string without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
key1_last_used="Null"
```

Below works

```
echo $(date "+%B %d %Y" ) $key1_last_used
```